# Extending Bokeh to match D3.js

Tags: javascript, python, d3.js, visualization, bokeh

As I understand it, [Bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org) looks to provide for Python, similar capability that [D3.js](http://d3js.org/) provides for JavaScript. Some advantages for Bokeh I can see include the use of HTML Canvas (so we can render more to the browser), [Abstract Rendering](https://github.com/JosephCottam/AbstractRendering) and a lower barrier to entry for people familiar with Python over JavaScript but wanting to develop interactive browser based visualisations.

This is great but, where do you go (i.e. as a developer) to extend Bokeh to match the flexibility offered by D3 e.g. to add Chord diagrams, Network graphs or develop more novel visualisations such as those demonstrated at [IEEE VIS](http://ieeevis.org/) or the [VAST challenge](http://vacommunity.org/VAST+Challenge+2015)?

Does the Bokeh project have aspirations to become as fully featured as D3 (appreciate D3 has been around for a while now)?

Answer (score 0):

They [do want to be fully featured as D3](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/):

> Its goal is to provide elegant, concise construction of novel graphics in the style of D3.js, and to extend this capability with high-performance interactivity over very large or streaming datasets. Bokeh can help anyone who would like to quickly and easily create interactive plots, dashboards, and data applications.

This is detailed in their [technical vision page](http://bokehplots.com/pages/technical-vision.html).

To help extend Bokeh, check the [extending Bokeh page](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/extensions.html#userguide-extensions) and the example of [wrapping a JS library (visjs)](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/extensions_gallery/wrapping.html). There is also a [developer guide](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/dev_guide.html#devguide) and a [enhancement proposal document](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/wiki/BEP-1:-Issues-and-PRs-management).

It would be awesome to have something like D3's transitions!